# Default of "absolute" positioning and "relative" positioning

Tags: html, css

I read up on relative and absolute positioning, but i'm still confused on what happens when you don't specify "top, left, right, bottom" after you choose one of the positions.  For example, in the code below, i changed the position for container and the footer does some funky stuff when I change it from relative to absolute. I read that if you add "position:relative" and don't specify any directions, it'll just stay exactly where it was meant to be.  But using firebug, i toggled that line in the css, and the menu bar on top would shift a little to the left. what is going on?

HTML:

```
    <div class="container">

        <div id="header">

            <ul id="menu">
                <li><a href="#" class="active">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Request a Quote</a></li>
            </ul>       

            <div id="logo">
                <h1>Creatif</h1>
                <small>A Family of Rockstar Wordpress Themes
            </div>
        </div><!--end header-->

        <div id="block_feature">
        Featured Content
        </div>      

        <div id="block_content">
        Content

        </div>

    </div>

</div>


<div id="footer">

    <div class="container">
        Footer stuff goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "UTF-8";  
/* Background-Styles */  

body {  
    margin:0px; padding:0px;  
    background-color:#131211;  
 }  
#main {  
    background:#c4c0be url(images/background_light_slice.jpg) repeat-x;  
}   
#main .container {  
    background-image:url(images/background_light.jpg);    
    background-repeat:no-repeat;  
    min-height:400px;  
}  

#header {  
    padding-top:20px;  
 }  
#logo h1, #logo small {  
    margin:0px;  
    display:block;  
    text-indent:-9999px;  
}  
#logo {  
    background-image:url(images/logo.png);  
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:194px;  
    height:83px;  
}  
ul#menu {  
    margin:0px; padding:0px;  
    position:absolute;  
    right:0px;  
}  
ul#menu li {  
   display:inline;   
}




#footer {  
    background-image:url(images/background_footer.jpg);  
    background-repeat:repeat-x;  
    color:white;  
    padding:40px;  
}  
.container {  
    width:950px;  
    margin:0 auto;  
    position:relative;  
}
```

with position:relative
[image]

with position: absolute
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the #footer div to position relative because the container needs to be absolute to a relative position.  Right now the footer is not relative so the #container defaults to whichever relative div is closest to the parent.  A rule of thumb is to always have the container div a relative when using absolute positioning.

```
#footer {position: relative; }
#container { position: absolute; }
```

Now if you add top: 0 to container it will be top: 0 to the footer.

Answer (score 0):

Chad's answer is correct.  Here's an explanation:

Setting a div to use absolute position makes it absolute in relation to the first parent node whose position is either absolute or relative.

In your example, since no parent node was set to position relative or absolute, the node was absolute in relationship to the body. As Chad mentioned, make sure to set the reference node to position: relative.